# Rank-one positive decomposition for a entry-wise positive positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have asked this question in [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365350/decomposing-a-entry-wise-positive-positive-semidefinite-matrix) without any success.

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix and also such that each of its entries is positive. Does $\mathbf{A}$ have a decomposition of the form
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \,=\,\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathbf{y}_i\mathbf{y}_i^T
\end{align}
where each vector $\mathbf{y}$ is also entry-wise positive and $k\leq n$.

Comment: Your matrix is doubly nonnegative http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublyNonnegativeMatrix.html  and your question is equivalent to asking if every such matrix is completely positive. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletelyPositiveMatrix.html Unfortunaley mathworld only states the other direction which is trivial but maybe you find something in the references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there exist doubly nonnegative matrices which are not completely positive, see for example [The difference between 5 x 5 doubly nonnegative and completely positive matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437950900281X) (2009).

A graph-based characterization of doubly nonnegative matrices which are completely positive is: *Every doubly nonnegative matrix realization of a graph $G$ is completely positive if and only if $G$ does not contain an odd cycle of length at least 5*, see [Open problems in the theory of completely positive and copositive matrices](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0daf/f8a13a4afebbfc4b39b7393e6c2b626d3a7f.pdf) (2015).

An alternative characterization is give in a 2011 [MO question:](https://mathoverflow.net/q/67641/11260) *A doubly nonnegative $n\times n$ matrix is completely positive if and only if the $n$
 vectors making up the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) lie in the non-negative orthant of some space of dimension $>n$.*

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.

If this would hold, all components of the $y_i$ would be bounded in terms of $A$; so, by compactness argument, the same would hold for matrices and columns with *non-negative* entries. We will show that this is not the case.

Let $I$ and $J$ be the identty and the all-ones matrices of order $3\times3$. Set
$$
  A=\left[\matrix{ 100I&J\\J&100I}\right].
$$
Then each $y_i$ may contain at most one non-zero among the first three entries, the same for the last three. On the other hand, for each $a=1,2,3$ and $b=4,5,6$ there should be a $y_i$ with non-zero $a$th and $b$th entries. Thus $k\geq9$.

**Remark.** This argument shows that, in general, $k\geq [n^2/4]$. It cannot show more, since the edges of an arbitrary graph on $n$ vertices may be split into at most $n^2/4$ cliques. It may happen that this estimate is sharp.